# Trigonometry proof involving sum difference and product formula

Tags: trigonometry

How would I solve the following trig problem.

$$\cos^5x = \frac{1}{16} \left( 10 \cos x + 5 \cos 3x + \cos 5x \right)$$

I am not sure what to really I know it involves the sum and difference identity but I know not what to do.

Comment: hint: rewrite $\cos x$ with exponentials and expand the fifth power : the binomial coefficients are [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

Comment: I am not sure how I would that theorem.

Comment: $\cos(x)=\frac 12 (e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$ so that $\cos(x)^5=\frac 1{2^5} (e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^5$, using binomial theorem is faster for the term at the right but it is not an obligation!

Comment: I have not studied e^ix or complex numbers unfortunately.

Comment: you may try it in the other direction $\cos(5x)=\cos(4x+x)=\cos(4x)\cos(x)-\sin(4x)\sin(x)$ and so on if you know the trigonometric rules for addition and no rules for powers...

Comment: Yes I know the ones for addition but the ones for powers I will learn one day.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you're trying to **solve** that problem - this would mean finding those values of $x$ for which it is true.  You're actually trying to **prove** a trigonometric identity, not solve an equation.  If you don't ask your questions carefully, you could lead potential answerers down a garden path.

Answer (score 3):

Taking you at your word that you know (or can derive)

> $\cos 3x = 4\cos^3x-3\cos x$
>
> $\cos 5x = 16\cos^5 x-20\cos^3 x+5\cos x$

all you have to do then is substitute these equalities into $(1/16)(10\cos x + 5\cos 3x + \cos 5x)$ and you'll find that it's equal to $\cos^5x$.

Comment: I like this response.

Answer (score 0):

$$\require{cancel}
\frac1{16} [ 5(\cos 3x+\cos x)+\cos 5x+5\cos x ]\\
=\frac1{16}[10\cos x \cos 2x+ \cos 5x +5 \cos x]\\
=\frac1{16} [5\cos x(2\cos 2x+1)+\cos 5x]\\
=\frac1{16} [5\cos x(2(2\cos^2 x-1)+1)+\cos 5x]\\
=\frac1{16} [5\cos x(4\cos^2 x-1)+\cos 5x]\\
=\frac1{16} [5\cos x(4\cos^2 x-1)+\cos 5x]\\
=\frac1{16} [20\cos^3 x-5\cos x+\cos 5x]\\
=\frac1{16} [20\cos^3 x-5\cos x+\cos 5x]\\
=\frac1{16} [\cancel{20\cos^3 x}\cancel{-5\cos x}+16\cos^5 x\cancel{-20\cos^3 x}+\cancel{5\cos x}]\\
=\frac1{16} (16\cos^5 x)\\=\cos^5 x$$

Answer (score 0):

Applying the same approach as that of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180008/prove-cos2x-sin4x-frac1322-cos2x-2-cos4x-cos6x/180032#180032),

let $A\cos5x+B\cos3x+C\cos x=\cos^5x$

As  $\cos 3x = 4\cos^3x-3\cos x$ and 
 $\cos 5x = 16\cos^5 x-20\cos^3 x+5\cos x$

$A(16\cos^5 x-20\cos^3 x+5\cos x) + B( 4\cos^3x-3\cos x)+ C\cos x=\cos^5x$

Comparing the coefficients of different powers of cosx,

5th power=>16A=1=>$A=\frac{1}{16}$ ,

3rd power=>-20A+4B=0=>B=5A=$\frac{5}{16}$ and

1st power=>5A-3B+C=0=>C=3B-5A$=3\cdot\frac{5}{16}-5\cdot\frac{1}{16}=\frac{5}{8}$

---

Alternatively, observe that the 3rd power of $\cos x$ is absent in the given expression.

But $A\cos5x+B\cos3x=A(16\cos^5 x-20\cos^3 x+5\cos x) + B( 4\cos^3x-3\cos x)$

$=16A\cdot\cos^5 x+ \cos^3x\cdot4(B-5A)+\cos x(5A-3B)$

So, B must be 5A to eliminate $cos^3x$

$A\cos5x+B\cos3x=A(\cos5x+5\cdot\cos3x)=A(16\cdot\cos^5 x - 10\cdot\cos x)$

Putting A=1, $\cos5x+5\cdot\cos3x=16\cdot\cos^5 x - 10\cdot\cos x$

So, we just need a little rearrangement.